# Spock - Do not run Specs simultaneously

Tags: gradle, spock

I'm running functional tests using Spock where the tests manipulate the database, and the Specs can conflict with each other if run simultaneously. From my web debugger, it appears that when I run `gradle test` that the calls to the web service from different Specs are being called simultaneously. The Specs themselves are being called with the `@Stepwise` annotation, and the tests are run in the correct order. How can I have Specs run separately in some order? They do not need to run in any specific order.

Comment: Maybe you'll find this answer helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28189180/542270. Since spock is JUnit compatible, defining a suite may be the way to go.

Comment: Making a test suite worked. Thank you!